# Data Filter SAS VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sas

```
data.Filter = "(Dec = 'Okay' AND no = '001' AND date >=" &
Sheets("parameter").range("A1") & ")" & _"or (Dec = 'Okay' AND 
(criteria = 'TOM1' OR criteria = 'TOM2' OR criteria = 'TOM3') AND 
date >=" & Sheets("parameter").range("A1") & ")"
```

Why does it show a run time error? I believe the problem starts from the filter consisting "criteria". How do I make things right?

**NOTE:** By adding additional line is no longer allowed as the maximum number of line is at 24, and i already exceeded it.

Comment: Is there a reason for the SAS tag?

Comment: This VBA is connected to SAS

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of the date values you're passing in from `Sheets("parameter").range("A1")`.

Assuming you're passing in a value from A1 of `20JAN2015` for example, you could try something along the lines of the below:

```
data.Filter = "(Dec = 'Okay' AND no = '001' AND date >='" &
Sheets("parameter").range("A1") & "'d)" & "or (Dec = 'Okay' AND 
(criteria = 'TOM1' OR criteria = 'TOM2' OR criteria = 'TOM3') AND 
date >='" & Sheets("parameter").range("A1") & "'d)"
```

This would give:

```
(Dec = 'Okay' AND no = '001' AND date >='20JAN2015'd) or (Dec = 'Okay' AND 
(criteria = 'TOM1' OR criteria = 'TOM2' OR criteria = 'TOM3') AND 
date >='20JAN2015'd)
```

Compare this with:

```
data _null_ ;
  datetxt='20JAN2015' ;
  datenum='20JAN2015'd ;
  put "Date as text " datetxt= ;
  put "Date as SAS date " datenum= ;
run ;
```

Comment: Actually, I think you have an unwanted `_` immediately before `"or (Dec = 'Okay' AND`...

Comment: The problem that occurred, I believe is due to the bracketing inside a bracketing. The syntax of AND or OR cannot simply read the bracketing inside the bracketing